# is operator always results to false in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I have this code:

```
    public ICommand ChangePageCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.changePageCommand == null)
            {
                this.changePageCommand = new ActionCommand(
                    parameter => {
                            this.ChangeViewModel((IPageViewModel)parameter);
                        },
                    parameter => parameter is IPageViewModel);
            }

            return this.changePageCommand;
        }
    }
```

Whenever I call this particular command, passing a `IPageViewModel` implementing class, the second parameter for `ActionCommand`, which is the predicate, always is false. I basically have all the `IPageViewModel`s in a dictionary. This is my entire ViewModel class:

```
using VexLibrary.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using VexLibrary.DesktopClient.ViewModels;
using System.Linq;

namespace VexLibrary.DesktopClient.ViewModels
{
    class ApplicationViewModel : ViewModel
    {
        private ICommand changePageCommand;
        private IPageViewModel currentPageViewModel;
        private Dictionary<string, IPageViewModel> pageViewModels;

        public ApplicationViewModel()
        {
            this.PageViewModels.Add("Dashboard", new DashboardViewModel(this));
            this.PageViewModels.Add("Statistics", new StatisticsViewModel());

            this.CurrentPageViewModel = this.PageViewModels["Dashboard"];
        }

        public ICommand ChangePageCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.changePageCommand == null)
                {
                    this.changePageCommand = new ActionCommand(
                        parameter => {
                                this.ChangeViewModel((IPageViewModel)parameter);
                            },
                        parameter => parameter is IPageViewModel);
                }

                return this.changePageCommand;
            }
        }



        public IPageViewModel CurrentPageViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                return this.currentPageViewModel;
            }
            set
            {
                if (this.currentPageViewModel != value)
                {
                    this.currentPageViewModel = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public Dictionary<string, IPageViewModel> PageViewModels
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.pageViewModels == null)
                    this.pageViewModels = new Dictionary<string, IPageViewModel>();

                return this.pageViewModels;
            }
        }


        public void ChangeViewModel(IPageViewModel viewModel)
        {
            this.CurrentPageViewModel = this.pageViewModels.FirstOrDefault(element => element.Value == viewModel).Value;
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, although the parameter implements the `IPageViewModel`, it always results to false. Here's my `ActionCommand` class:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace VexLibrary.Windows
{
    public sealed class ActionCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Action<Object> action;
        private readonly Predicate<Object> predicate;
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ActionCommand"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="action">The <see cref="Action"/> delegate to wrap.</param>
        public ActionCommand(Action<Object> action) : this(action, null)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ActionCommand"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="action">The <see cref="Action"/> delegate to wrap.</param>
        /// <param name="predicate">The <see cref="Predicate{Object}"/> that determines whether the action delegate may be invoked.</param>
        public ActionCommand(Action<Object> action, Predicate<Object> predicate)
        {
            if (action == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("action", "You must specify an Action<T>.");
            }

            this.action = action;
            this.predicate = predicate;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Defines the method that determines whether the command can execute in its current state.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// true if this command can be executed; otherwise, false.
        /// </returns>
        /// <param name="parameter">Data used by the command.  If the command does not require data to be passed, this object can be set to null.</param>
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            if (predicate == null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return predicate(parameter);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Defines the method to be called when the command is invoked.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="parameter">Data used by the command.  If the command does not require data to be passed, this object can be set to null.</param>
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            action(parameter);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Executes the action delegate without any parameters.
        /// </summary>
        public void Execute()
        {
            Execute(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a use case:

```
                        <Button Command="{Binding ChangePageCommand}"  CommandParameter="{Binding PageViewModels[Dashboard]}">
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TitleBarIcon}" Text="&#xE10F;" />
                        </Button>
```

The thing here is, `CanExecute` always evaluates to false, hence, the Button click is disable here. But, I tried replacing the predicate to just `true` which makes the program work totally as expected. Here's the DashboardViewModel which is what I'm passing to the command here:

```
using VexLibrary.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace VexLibrary.DesktopClient.ViewModels
{
    class DashboardViewModel : ViewModel, IPageViewModel
    {
        private string name = "Dashboard";
        private ApplicationViewModel parentViewModel;
        private ICommand statisticsPageCommand;

        public DashboardViewModel(ApplicationViewModel parentViewModel)
        {
            this.parentViewModel = parentViewModel;
        }

        public ICommand StatisticsPageCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new ActionCommand(
                    parameter => this.parentViewModel.ChangeViewModel(this.parentViewModel.PageViewModels["Statistics"])
                );
            }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return this.name;
            }
            set
            {
                this.name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried breaking into this in the debugger, and seeing what the actual value of `parameter` is?

Comment: @JonSkeet The parameter value is perfectly correct because when I set the predicate to true, the CanExecute evaluates to true. Hence, the program works perfectly.

Comment: That didn't actually answer my question... and as Jürgen Röhr noted, it's possible that it's null.

Comment: @JonSkeet While debugging, I did find a null exception in the CanExecute method. You were right. But placing the CommandParameter before the Command attribute made this work perfectly. Why is this behaving like this?

Comment: I've no idea about the WPF side of things. I was only commenting on the basic diagnostic approach... if something isn't behaving as you expect to, it's worth looking in the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the xaml of the button the otherway around so the CommandParameter is evaluated before the command.

```
<Button CommandParameter="{Binding PageViewModels[Dashboard]}" Command="{Binding ChangePageCommand}">
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TitleBarIcon}" Text="&#xE10F;" />
</Button>
```

Also when you change the CommandParameter's binding, you need to manually force the command's CanExecuteChanged evaluation.

You are probably better off using just the name as the parameter however.

```
<Button Command="{Binding ChangePageCommand}" CommandParameter="Dashboard">
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TitleBarIcon}" Text="&#xE10F;" />
</Button>
```

And in the viewmodel make following changes.

```
public ICommand ChangePageCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new Command(
                parameter => { this.ChangeViewModel(parameter as string); },
                parameter =>
                    {
                        var str = parameter as string;
                        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) && this.PageViewModels.ContainsKey(str);
                    });
    }
}

public void ChangeViewModel(string viewName)
{
    this.CurrentPageViewModel = this.pageViewModels.FirstOrDefault(element => element.Key == viewName).Value;
}
```

Comment: @JanneMatikanien How would I force CanExecuteChanged evaluation?

Comment: Why is it behaving like that? I placed the CommandParameter before, and it now works flawlessly. ;)

Comment: This is not however the real answer to your problems binding from a dictionary, which might be the cause of this behavior, you could try binding to a ObservableCollection<T> and have a value converter with parameter to select specific instance from the collection to get notification support for your bindings. Otherwise you might have figure out to make a performant solution to do the CanExecute re-evaluation over the CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested() which would re-evaluate all command bindings.

Comment: Thanks. I get it now.

Answer (score 2):

As the `parameter` is the same to both `CanExecute` and `Execute`, the only way for your snippet

```cs
this.changePageCommand = new ActionCommand(
  parameter => { this.ChangeViewModel((IPageViewModel)parameter); },
  parameter => parameter is IPageViewModel);
```

to not throw an exception in the first assignment (explicit casting) and to yield null as result in the second assignment is, to pass `null` as parameter. So check for null and react appropriatly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This wasn't the solution, but I want to know more about what you are saying. Could you please explain further, as well as use simple terms in doing so? (My english skills are horrible).

Comment: Your xaml says `CommandParameter="{Binding PageViewModels[Dashboard]}"`. Whatever the value of `PageViewModels[Dashboard]` is, is passed to either `CanExecute` and `Execute`. If this value can't be cast into `IPageViewModel`, the `Execute` code would throw an `InvalidCastException`. So the value must be castable (or your question would have been a different one). The only value, that is castable into `IPageViewModel` and results in `null` when used in `... as IPageViewModel` is `null` itself. Better explained now?

Comment: Just thinking about it and seeing my own mistake: `Execute` is never called as `CanExecute` always returns `false`.